# Can The same GG node serves both roles: IMDB and Compute?

Tags: gridgain

I would like to do "some calculation" on each In Memory DataBase(IMDB) GridGain (GG) node which continue receiving new data.
While looking at GG examples it seems a node must be started either as data node or as compute node.
Alternative GG architectural ideas would be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Note for anyone else who (like me) has no idea what this question is about: apparently IMDB = In Memory Database and GG = GridGain, an in-memory computing platform, see http://www.gridgain.org

Answer (score 1):

The GridGain Data Grid edition (which I think you are referring to) includes Compute functionality. If you start GridGain node with any configuration, Compute functionality is included by default.

Alternatively if you, for example, would like data grid and streaming functionality together, you may download the *platform* edition which includes everything.